# Adding text to a python generated image

Tags: python, image, qr-code

I have a python read a serial port and then create a QR code from this data.  What I want to do is add the data used to make the QR code into the image that is generated.

```
qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=1,
    box_size=10,
)
data1 = arduino.readline()
shadata1 = hashlib.sha1(data1).hexdigest()

qrdata = data1 + shadata1[0] + shadata1[1] + shadata1[2] + shadata1[3] + shadata1[4] + shadata1[5]
qr.add_data(qrdata)
qr.make(fit=True)

img = qr.make_image()
img_file = "/" + data1 + ".png"
img.save(img_file, 'PNG')
```

So at the moment I get a QR code generated and saved,
I want to have the following

```
 _____________
|             |  "Title"
|             |  Data1
|             |  "Pin Code"
|             |  shadata1[0] shadata1[1] shadata1[2] shadata1[3] shadata1[4] shadata1[5]
|             |
|_____________|
```

I have no idea how I would actually carry that out.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [Python Image Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) you can manipulate images, including adding text to them.

Note that the PIL is only available for Python 2.x. v3 support is on it's way.

Comment: There is nice tutorial with examples [here](http://nadiana.com/pil-tutorial-basic-advanced-drawing#Drawing_Text).

Comment: I cant figure out how to add whitespace to the image to add text as the qrcode library outputs just a single image.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572691/in-python-python-image-library-1-1-6-how-can-i-expand-the-canvas-without-resiz) answer, you can best just create a new image with the required size and paste the old image into that.

Comment: Can it append text to SVG?