# enlarge the upper margin of the image, keeping the background the same color python

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, tesseract, opencv, python

Is it possible to enlarge the upper margin of the image, keeping the background the same color? I have tried cv2 and pillow, but could not. It is to improve the scraping of image web pages with scrapy and tesseract in python

**Input**
[image]

**Output**
[image]

[image]

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
url = "https://www.yapo.cl/pg/0lu3quB3xJWOOJl5r7RBle3TME2kepf9ahuvYSfPYiA==.gif"

img = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
img.save("image.png")
image = cv2.imread("image.png",0)
image = imutils.resize(image, width=400)
cv2.imshow('thresh', image)
cv2.waitKey()
kernel = np.ones((2,2), np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('thresh', image)
cv2.waitKey()
image = cv2.erode(image, kernel, iterations=1)
cv2.imshow('thresh', image)
cv2.waitKey()


image = cv2.dilate(image, kernel, iterations=1)
cv2.imshow('thresh', image)
cv2.waitKey()

image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (7,7), 0)
#result = 255 - thresh
image = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
phone = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config="-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789+() --psm 6").strip()

print(phone)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks, *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text. *"I have tried cv2 and pillow, but could not"* is not a valid problem statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, Python Image Library 1.1.6, how can I expand the canvas without resizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572691/in-python-python-image-library-1-1-6-how-can-i-expand-the-canvas-without-resiz)

Comment: thx u  @MattDMo but the image becomes blurry when doing the process